# How to push rootviewcontroller in Ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I push new StatusViewController(i created UITabbarViewController programmically in it) from rootviewController (UInavigation controller). Now, i want to click on logout button, it push rootviewcontroller but i used below code, it push rootviewcontroller fine but it still tabbar at the bottom.

This code to call rootviewcontroller:

```
    LoginTab *loginView = [[LoginTab alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:loginView animated:YES];
    [loginView release];
```

And this code is created UItabbarcontroller in StatusViewController:

```
self.tab=[[UITabBarController alloc]init];

UploadTab *uploadview=[[UploadTab alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *uploadTabItem = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: uploadview] autorelease];
uploadview.title=@"Uploading";
uploadview.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Uploading.png"];
self.title = @"FirstViewControllerTitle";

//SecondViewController
ConvertTab *convertView=[[ConvertTab alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *convertTabItem = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: convertView] autorelease];
convertView.title=@"Convert";
convertView.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Convert.png"];

//ThirdViewController
CompletedTab *completedView=[[CompletedTab alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *completedTabItem = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: completedView] autorelease];
completedView.title=@"Completed";
completedView.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Completed.png"];
UIBarButtonItem * LogoutItem= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logout.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(logout)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = LogoutItem;
self.tab.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:uploadTabItem,convertTabItem, completedTabItem, nil];

// [self.view insertSubview:self.tab.view belowSubview: uploadview.view];
[self presentModalViewController:self.tab animated:NO];
```

You can see this image :
[image]

Comment: You don't want to push to root, you want to POP to root

Answer (score 3):

Use `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` method instead of `pushViewController`:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:animated];
```

Comment: It's the correct solution.  Can you post the code where you tried it?

Comment: I mean in particular, the code that attempts the pop.  The code in the question shows how you get to the pushed VC, but the problem in the question is how to get back from it.  Also, when you add code, please include a comment like // this is MyVC.m and a method name like -(void)viewWillAppear, or whatever where the posted code is contained.

Answer (score 0):

Your hierarchy does not seem correct. Your tab bar controller should be the root view controller. For each tab, you can have a navigation controller which has its own controllers to push and pop. That said, your tab bar will always be visible since that is the behavior that is expected when you have a tab bar based app. If you want to present a view which does not show a tab bar, you will need to present that view controller as a Modal view controller on top of your tab bar controller.

Comment: I updated my code in question. Can you please help me? I used UINavigation for each tabbar item. I push StatusVIewController (including tabbar controller) from rootviewcontroller. Now, i want to back rootviewcontroller. I don't know how can do that?

Comment: Don't present the tab as modal view. Your tab bar controller should be your root view controller which is fine. Your navigation controllers are also fine. I am not clear where you want the logout button. When you click logout, present the LoginViewController as a modal view controller. Do not push loginViewController into any navigation controller.